# media play length

Tags: windows-media-center, windows-media-player, media

Is one of the defining characteristics of any computer media file that it has a total play length tag embedded somewhere in its encoding? And if so, one that can be read by any machine?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format.  Some formats include a record for this (possibly at the beginning or at the end of the file).  Which format(s) are you interested in?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Randolph.  The formats are .ts, .mpg, .mov, .mp4, and .vob.